# Expectation of $\frac{1}{X+1}$ for a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am confused over $\mathbb E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right)$ where $X$ is geometric distribution with parameter $p$. The book wants me to prove that $\mathbb E(\frac{1}{1+X})=\log\left((1-p)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\right)$

Here's what I did.

$$\mathbb E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr(X=k) \frac{1}{1+k}=\sum \frac{p^k (1-p)}{1+k}=\frac{1-p}{p}\sum \frac{p^{k+1}}{1+k}=\frac{1-p}{p} \left(-\log(1-p)\right)=\log\left((1-p)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\right)\text.$$

I don't see a problem with my calculation and I checked with wolfram alpha... it showed that I am right.

Could anyone help?

Comment: In my book, geometric distribution has pmf $p(1-p)^k$ rather than the other way around.

Comment: yeah in the book Probability Essentials it is defined a little bit strangely but this does not influence the calculation of the series

Comment: It does... I haven't checked carefully, but it seems to yield $\log\left(p^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\right)$.

Comment: I do think the book is somewhat wrong...

Comment: Random variable $X$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p$ can mean several different things. $X$ could be the number of successes until the first failure, and $p$ is the probability of success. Or $p$ is the probability of failure. Or $X$ is the number of trials until the first success. The various choices will give different but related answers for your problem.

Comment: yeap, actually I checked all the possibilities, still contradicting the book

Comment: yeah right. So I am now pretty sure the book is wrong!

Comment: Could you please give us the title and author of the book?

Comment: probability essentials, philip protter

Comment: $ q \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k/(1+k) = {- \frac q r \ln (1-r)} =  \ln (1-r)^{-  q / r}$ So by substituting: $(1-p) \sum_k p^k/(1+k) = \ln (1-p)^{-(1-p)/p}$

Comment: problem 5.17 :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The expectation of $\frac{1}{1+X}$ where $X$ is Geometric($p$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589238/the-expectation-of-frac11x-where-x-is-geometricp)